# sailsjs using pm2 cluster mode and CSRF

Tags: sails.js, csrf, pm2

I am running a sailsjs app with `pm2` and its cluster mode.

The problem now is that since I am making cross domain requests with CSRF validation, only one of the clusters has the right access, the others give me the "CSRF mismatch error".

How do you use the pm2 with CSRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) has built-in support for using Redis or MongoDB to share session state across a cluster, for example with modulus.io, Heroku, or a self-hosted cluster using pm2. You can set the configuration values for this in `config/session.js`.

See:

- [setting up a redis shared session store](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.session.html?q=shared-redis-session-store)
- [`config/session.js` reference](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/session.js.html)
- [`config/csrf.js` reference](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.csrf.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly with the CSRF, and so simple (yey! sails). But now my sockets are logging like crazy. They seem to connect and reconnect exhaustibly. Do you know what might has happened?

Comment: I face similar issues like Juan. It seems that pm2 tries to initiate a new session with the cluster workers frequently leading to endless new session creation